# Gradle Build failed with an exception android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Hi i am having trouble generating apk and give this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find ir.tapsell.plus:tapsell-plus-sdk-android:1.1.1.
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
```

What should I do now to solve the problem? please guide me

Comment: Gradle can not resolve your dependency for library `ir.tapsell.plus:tapsell-plus-sdk-android:1.1.1`
Please add your module gradle and project gradle files to verify the cuase and provide solution.

Comment: Can you link to a tutorial or other steps you've been following? It's hard to know what led you to this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sample app](https://github.com/tapsellorg/TapsellPlusSDK-AndroidSample) explains that TapsellPlus SDK is downloaded from a third-party repo, which you need to specify in your root `build.gradle`.

```
allprojects {  
    repositories {  
        google()  
        jcenter()  

        maven { // THIS
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/tapsellorg/maven'  
        }
    }  
}
```